# How to dynamically generate SQL query based on user’s selections?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

This is the same question as:

[How to dynamically generate SQL query based on user's selections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040680/how-to-dynamically-generate-sql-query-based-on-users-selections)

The only difference is, that I'm interested in seeing solutions also using Java/JPA (+possibly EclipseLink or Hibernate specific extensions).

I need to create a GUI, using which users can select several attributes which will be used to query the database to find suitable persons. I'm looking for ideas how to dynamically generate the database query according to user's choices.

Query will contain several fields, but to get the idea I will include only three of those below as an example:

- **Occupation** - there can be 0 to n occupation strings. If occupation strings are given, one of them have to match.
- **Age** - age can be given as:

  1. exact match (30)
  2. range (e.g. 30-40)
  3. less than a value (-40)
  4. more than a value (30-)

Age parameter is optional in the query. In addition, user can specify whether age is a required parameter. If it's not required, and a person does not have age is his/her profile, age criteria is ignored for this person.

- **Height** - similar as age

**Example queries:**

No criteria has been given:

```
select * from persons
```

Only occupation has been given:

```
select * from persons where occupation = 'dentist'
```

Several occupations have been given:

```
select * from persons where (occupation = 'dentist' or occupation = 'engineer')
```

Age has been given as a greater than value, and it's required to exist on person's profile:

```
select * from persons where age >= 30
```

Height has been given as a range, and it's not required to exist on person's profile:

```
select * from persons where (height is null or (height >= 30 and height <= 40))
```

Combination of different criteria:

```
select * from persons where occupation = 'dentist' and age >= 30 and (height is null or (height >= 30 and height <= 40))
```

I have already implemented code which is capable of generating queries as strings, but it certainly is not too pretty. I'm looking for ideas what would be the most efficient and prettiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hibernate, you can use [Criteria](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) queries.

In Toplink, we got [Expression, and ExpressionBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/doc/1013/main/_html/expres.htm#CJAGGAGJ).

Answer (score 3):

There are many different tools the best i think are [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/), [torpedoquery](http://torpedoquery.org/) e [Object Query](http://objectquery.org), this three allow to write typesafe query, otherwise you can use criteria api, and if you are using jpa 2 also [JPA2 Typesafe Query](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/).

with all this tools you can build a query at runtime!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in JPA 1.X, you can use custom query builder as described here http://rrusin.blogspot.com/2010/02/jpa-query-builder.html. 
This enables creating queries like this:

```
return new JpaQueryBuilder().buildQuery(em,
                new Object[] {
                    "select c from Car c where c.name is not null",
                    new JQBParam("name", name, " and c.name = :name"),
                    new JQBParam("type", type, " and c.type = :type")
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) framework because I'm using JPA 1.0 which does not include the Criteria API and I also needed the features you described. Writing Querydsl code is easy and the code is shorter than Criteria API code. Querydsl is free to use and it supports typesafe queries.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I'm using `AND` and `OR` objects for this. They take lists as parameters (looks nice with Java 5's variadic arguments) and concatenate them in Strings with the necessary spaces and parentheses. Pseudo code:

```
AND(WhereCond ... conds) { this.conds = conds; }
toString() { return conds.length == 0 ? "" : "(" + join(conds, " AND ") + ")" };
```

where `join()` converts the object array to string array and then joins the elements with the parameter.