# Java dynamically generate SQL query - ATHENA

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to generate sql query based on user input. There are 4 search fields on the UI:
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SUBJECT, MARKS

Based on user input I am planning to generate SQL query. Input can be of any combination.

eg: `select * from TABLE where FIRST_NAME="some_value";`

This query needs to be generated when FIRST_NAME is given and other fields are null

`select  * from TABLE where FIRST_NAME="some_value" and LAST_NAME="some_value";`

This query needs to be generated when FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME are given and other fields are null

Since there are 4 input fields, number of possible queries that can be generated are 24 (factorial of 4).

One idea is to write if condition for all 24 cases.

Java pseudo code:

```
String QUERY = "select * from TABLE where ";

if (FIRST_NAME!=null) {

    QUERY = QUERY + "FIRST_NAME='use_input_value';"

}
if (LAST_NAME!=null) {

    QUERY = QUERY + "LAST_NAME='use_input_value';"

}
if (SUBJECT!=null) {

    QUERY = QUERY + "SUBJECT='use_input_value';"

}
if (MARKS!=null) {

    QUERY = QUERY + "MARKS='use_input_value';"

}
```

I am not able to figure out how to generate SQL queries with AND coditions for multiple Input values.
I have been through concepts on dynamically generate sql query but couldn't process further.

Can someone help me on this.

FYI: I have been through [How to dynamically generate SQL query based on user's selections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040680/how-to-dynamically-generate-sql-query-based-on-users-selections), still not able to generate query string based on user input.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about what would happen if you just ran the code you wrote and both `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` are provided. You'll wind up with this:

```
select * from TABLE where FIRST_NAME='use_input_value';LAST_NAME='use_input_value';
```

There are two problems here:

1. The query is syntactically incorrect.
2. It contains the literals `'use_input_value'` instead of the values you want.

To fix the first problem, let's first add `and` to the start of each expression, and remove the semicolons, something like this:

```
String QUERY = "select * from TABLE where";
if (FIRST_NAME!=null) {
    QUERY = QUERY + " and FIRST_NAME='use_input_value'";
}
```

Notice the space before the `and`. We can also remove the space after `where`.

Now the query with both FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME will look like this:

```
select * from TABLE where and FIRST_NAME='use_input_value' and LAST_NAME='use_input_value'
```

Better but now there's an extra `and`. We can fix that by adding a dummy always-true condition at the start of the query:

```
String QUERY = "select * from TABLE where 1=1";
```

Then we append a semicolon after all the conditions have been evaluated, and we have a valid query:

```
select * from TABLE where 1=1 and FIRST_NAME='use_input_value' and LAST_NAME='use_input_value';
```

(It may not be necessary to append the semicolon. Most databases don't require semicolons at the end of a single query like this.)

On to the string literals. You should add a placeholder instead, and simultaneously add the value you want to use to a `List`.

```
String QUERY = "select * from TABLE where";
List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
if (FIRST_NAME!=null) {
    QUERY = QUERY + " and FIRST_NAME=?";
    args.add(FIRST_NAME);
}
```

After you've handled all the conditions you'll have a string with N '?' placeholders and a `List` with N values. At that point just [prepare a query](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) from the SQL string and add the placeholders.

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
    statement.setString(i + 1, args[i]);
}
```

For some reason columns and parameters are indexed starting at 1 in the JDBC API, so we have to add 1 to `i` to produce the parameter index.

Then execute the `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Is there is a way to build string instead of using PreparedStatement?

Comment: Also in String literal part string QUERY = "select * from TABLE where"; is used. Can you please explain why AND is not used here. 
Since I am ATHENA(AWS service, PRESTO based) to query I cannot use Prepared statements. I think I should go for option 1(1=1 condition).

Comment: Please suggest me any better approaches in case there are any. Once again thanks for detailed explanation

Comment: In this scenerio(where prepareStatement is not supported) I think I should got for string format to generate sql queries

Comment: If `FIRST_NAME` etc. are user input then you don't want to append them directly to the string due to https://xkcd.com/327. That's why you'd normally use a `PreparedStatement` with placeholders, to allow JDBC to properly escape or sanitize the input for you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection for alternatives.